# Using ingress host from k8s secret in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy a service using helm. The cluster is Azure AKS & I have one DNS zone associated with a cluster that can be used for ingress.

But the issue is that the DNS zone is in k8s secret & I want to use it in ingress as host. like below

```yaml
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Chart.Name }}.{{ .Values.tls.host }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Chart.Name }}.{{ .Values.tls.host }}
    http:
      paths:
        -
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              port:
                number: 80
          path: "/"
```

I want `.Values.tls.host` value from secret. Currently, it is hardcoded in `values.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

For the current version of Helm (3.8.0), it seems not possible to use values right from Secret **with standard approach**.
Based on the information from [Helm website](https://helm.sh/):

> A template directive is enclosed in `{{` and `}}` blocks.
> The values that are passed into a template can be thought of as *namespaced
> objects*, where a dot (`.`) separates each namespaced element.

[Objects are passed into a template from the template engine](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) and can be:

- Release
- Values
- Chart
- Files
- Capabilities
- Template

[Contents for Values objects can come from multiple sources](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/):

> - The  `values.yaml`  file in the chart
> - If this is a subchart, the  `values.yaml`  file of a parent chart
> - A values file if passed into  `helm install`  or  `helm upgrade`  with the  `-f`  flag (`helm install -f myvals.yaml ./mychart`)
> - Individual parameters passed with  `--set`  (such as  `helm install --set foo=bar ./mychart`)

Answer (score 0):

Helm cannot fetch values from Kubernetes, and ingress manifest do not support this type of reference.

You need to do this outside of helm and stitch the commands together, in your pipeline or from some script or manually in the shell.

```sh
helm install my-app chart/ \
 --set tls.host="$(kubectl get secret my-dns-zone \
   -o go-template='{{index .data "dns-zone" | base64decode }}')"
```